# How can I use an iPhone to "tag" a location using GPS so I can bookmark a location?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, gps, maps

I need to tag a "location" of interest such as

- An nest or hive out in nature where no cellular service is available
- Location of a good view on a mountain (where no cell service is visible)
- Location of a restaurant, bar, other spot that is hard to find.

And I'd like to get relative directions to where that target is (north 500 feet) without having to deal with apple maps, or better still, the ability to plant virtual waymarkers that guide me along the best path using GPS.

Does such a technology exist?

Answer (score 2):

I use the Maps app to drop a pin and then either save it later once I get data access or save it to a new contact and then work on it from the Contacts app at a later date.

This avoids needing a dedicated GPS app to save waypoints, but there are hundreds of those as well should you want to go shopping on the iTunes store for a more GPS like experience.

You can also get many apps to do this - here are the ones I like and use:

- [Pro Compass](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pro-compass/id517739197?mt=8) - most basic - compass and coordinates - no log file functionality.
- [Spyglass](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spyglass/id332639548?mt=8) - basic Augmented Reality (shows camera and an overlay of GPS and other data). No log file functionality, so you would save snapshots of the screen to the camera roll.
- [Theodolite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/theodolite/id339393884?mt=8) - Has log file functionality and all of the above. Can snap the screen easily, add annotations to the locations it logs, etc... A veritable swiss army knife.

[image: wild coffee shop]

None of the above apps need data connection - just your iPhone with enough battery charge to run.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question. But why not just take a photo of the location you want to tag. This will (unless you have turned off location services for the camera app) record the GPS information. You can then create an album with your tagged photos and view them in a map view on your phone

If you export the photos you can extract the GPS info using various tools (if you are on a Mac you can simply do a "Get info" on the picture to find the GPS location. If you want to automatise the process you could use a tool like [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).

Other possibilities are to get iPhone apps such as [MapPocket](http://mappocket.net/), where you can pre-download maps of the area you want to go (Also ideal for holidays abroad, to avoid roaming costs) and then view your location on the map.

Comment: +1 for this. I suspect the OP, like so many users, are unaware that Photos does this automatically. Once plotted in Maps it becomes easy to navigate, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoTags for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/geotags/id436134058?mt=8)

Maybe this App is a solution for you. You can tag your fav. spots and add images to each bookmark